# How are you suppose to determine wether an undirected tree is binary or not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

How do you determine wether a undirected tree is binary or not?

Are you supposed to choose a root and go from there?

One root might make the tree binary and another root might not make it binary.

Is it so if one root makes it not being binary then it is in general NOT binary or?

Comment: @DonThousand The problem im facing right now is, that its undirected, that would mean that I would be able to choose whatever vertex as root, but one of the vertexes would lead the tree into being a binary tree, while another vertex would make the tree not be binary.

Comment: Wait, I just noticed the graph is undirected. What does it mean for a graph to be binary when undirected??

Comment: @DonThousand That the edges don't have an "arrow" the edges are not directed.

Comment: Since in a binary tree you talk about children (and it is represented in a 'root' to leaves' kind of way, there is a direction to the connections: they are all away form the root. Since the original graph has no directions, the problem must be to figure out whether there is *some* way to create those directions to turn the undirected tree into a binary tree.  And yes, for some choices of root that may work, while for others it does not. My guess is that the question is asking you if you can pick *some* vertex as the root to turn it into a binary tree. But, you certainly raise a good question.

Comment: In a binary tree, the root has degree $2$, leaves have degree $1$, and all other nodes can have degree $2$ or $3$ depending on whether they have one child or two. That at least gives you a way to determine that a given tree is NOT binary.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know that the input T is a tree, then you need only to check that all vertices of T have 1-3 edges: this accounts for one to the parent and at most two to its children in a binary tree representation. If so, then T can be represented as a binary tree.

You don't need to check if a root exists because any tree (acyclic, connected, undirected graph) has a node with 1-2 edges that can act as the root. For example, any leaf of T has 1 edge and can serve as the root.